# gRPC support for .NET 3.5 framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, grpc

According to official grpc [documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html#before-you-begin), the grpc for C# requires at least .NET 4.5 framework.

I have a project that should be supported on Windows XP which is running .NET 3.5.

Is there any porting of grpc that can run on .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No plans to support .NET 3.5 - it's way too old and lacks some important APIs currently used by gRPC (most importantly async/await). More detail is here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7880

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out. it is claimed to be able to run on Windows XP SP3. The runtime Grpc.Core is running with .Net Framework 4.0

https://github.com/gavxin/grpc-win-xp